# Upgrading a special software (no matter if other softwares are up to date or outdated)

Tags: 12.04, installation, updates, software-updater

I just want to have the latest version of gimp.

I haven't updated some other softwares and I want to focus on updating gimp to the latest version right now.

Any software-specific command, or command that has a switch to act on specific software only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah. When you try to install a package that is already installed, it upgrades the package if an upgrade is available (and any version dependencies on other packages).

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install [PACKAGE(s)]
```

where `[PACKAGE(s)]` is/are the package(s) you wish to install.

Comment: but most of official ubuntu repositories don't update to the latest version,So maybe you have to add some more repositories from gimp or you have to compile gimp from source

Comment: Well, the Ubuntu versions usually go for latest stable, so I mean, if it was really necessary, you could build from source, but that seems a bit drastic to me...